# undefined method `question_answer' for #<Answer:

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid

Here are my two models

```
class Answer
  include Mongoid::Document

  belongs_to :question
  has_many :responses
  has_many :validations, :dependent => :delete
end
```

and

```
class Question
  include Mongoid::Document

  has_many :answers, :dependent => :delete # it might not always have answers
  belongs_to :correct_answer, :class_name => "Answer", :dependent => :delete
end
```

What is missing here? Not able to resolve it

Comment: Always add the whole stacktrace.

Comment: And why do you expect Answer to have a `question_answer` method? The only thing exists, is `belongs_to :question`, which adds only `question` method

Comment: Its error in Rails admin Not able to find why this association get fails

Comment: try `question_answers` ?